# Tridion Search User Credentials

Tags: 2013, configuration, search

My Tridion platform is 2013 SP1.

I ran into an issue on a development box where MTSUser's password had changed somehow. I reset the password, then changed it in the following locations:

- COM+
- SDL Tridion Content Manager configuration (Indexer service,
  query engine)

The CME boots fine and I can create components, publish pages etc. without issue. However, when I try to add a new user (search the domain), I get the following error:

`Unable to list users from
Access is denied.`

When this first happened, it was before I had changed the password in the SDL Tridion Content Manager configuration, and I got an error in the Security system log where MTSUser failed to authenticate (makes sense) when the TcmSearchHost.exe was invoked. However, after making the changes and restarting the server, I'm still getting the error, but it's no longer appearing as an audit failure in the security log. I am seeing a regular audit failure (every 10 mins exactly) but it's difficult for me to attribute this to anything because it comes in as NULL SID, DOMAIN\username and without any process information.

I also can't search the content manager, although this does not throw any errors and simply returns an empty search result.

Nothing is logged in the cd_core or any other Tridion log, even on TRACE, which is related to search.

Logging in to the localhost:8983 with MTSUser shows no logs either.

I'm out of ideas for where to look next for more information. Any suggestions would be welcome.

- Are there any other locations in the Tridion ecosystem where the password for MTSUser is explicitly used?
- Are there any other places I might look for logging/debugging information?
- Could this be a different issue than incorrect MTSUser credentials?

Comment: After changing the password, did you reset COM+, All Tridion Services and Content Manager App Pool in IIS (or may be IIS Reset)?

Comment: I did, and I also restarted the whole server.

Comment: By mistake is your MTS user be the impersonation user for the directory service and you forgot relevant changes in SDL Config Manager in those sections of Impersonation and Directory services

Comment: No, that's configured to be the network service user.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to search in MMC-Snapping in the Search Settings sections?

you have to check in Query engine Settnigs and Indexer Service Settings

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your tcm services may be configured to run under the MTSUser, so you most likely need to go into the properties of those under 'services' and re-enter the new password for the user.

Comment: None of the services are running under MTSUser. They are either under the local system account, or network service.

Comment: I did say 'May' I've seen instances where this has been the case.